# Strange issue when trying to dismiss UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that hold a `UITableView`, I want to dismiss the `UIViewController` when clicking on the table's cell. So I implemented the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Inside of this method I called:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

For some reason, when I click on the cell, the app freezes and I need to click once more in order the `UIViewController` to dismiss. I even put a breakpoint there to check if it reaches it on the first or the second tap and in the first tap it reaches the breakpoint, then I click on continue execution and I need to tap once more.

Did someone encountered this issue on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems like you use `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Make sure that you use **didSelect...**, not **didDeselect....**.

Second, It freezes because the method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called not on the main thread. You have to use GCD to execute your code in the main queue:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//  PLEASE TRY THIS.

[self.navigationController.popoverPresentationController];
```